# How to Auto Increment Assembly or Assembly File Version, from MSBuild?

Tags: msbuild, t4

Constraints are:
Using Visual Studio 2017.
Needs to ultimately be called from a powershell script calling MSBuild.

Not sure its relevant, but needs to be able to build the following:

- asp.net 461
- asp.net-core 1.1 and 2.0 assemblies

Unsuccessful attempts so far:

- [How to have an auto incrementing version number (Visual Studio)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826777/how-to-have-an-auto-incrementing-version-number-visual-studio#answer-827209) <- This works when building from VS only.
- [Code Generation in a Build Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/code-generation-in-a-build-process) -Described as Microsoft's latest document on using "TextTemplating" with MSBuild. States need to copy certain DLLs to build server..  Files are not located where specified in doc, and dont know *where to copy them*, I have found all files.  Additionally modified `.csproj's` import `Microsoft.TextTemplating.targets` path to correct location but when running MSBuild I get. "error MSB4018: The "TransformTemplates" task failed unexpectedly."
- [This SO Answer - MSBuild support for T4 templates in Visual Studio 2017 RTM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42662011/msbuild-support-for-t4-templates-in-visual-studio-2017-rtm#answer-42662267)
   <- Give same MSBuild Runtime error as above.

**Example attempt** of ["Code Generation in a Build Process"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/code-generation-in-a-build-process) That works on build from VS but not MSBuild:

placed in root of project - handleVersioning.tt:

```
<#@ template language="C#" #>

using System.Reflection;

[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.*")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("<#= this.Year #>.<#= this.Month #>.<#= this.Day #>.<#= this.Minute #>")]
<#+
    int Year = DateTime.UtcNow.Year;
    int Month = DateTime.UtcNow.Month;
    int Day = DateTime.UtcNow.Day;
    int Minute = unchecked((int)DateTime.UtcNow.TimeOfDay.TotalMinutes);
#>
```

.csproj:

```
<Import Project="...hardcoded...\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
<!-- This is the important line: -->  
<Import Project="...hardcoded...\TextTemplating\Microsoft.TextTemplating.targets" />

<PropertyGroup>  
    <TransformOnBuild>true</TransformOnBuild>  
    <OverwriteReadOnlyOutputFiles>true</OverwriteReadOnlyOutputFiles>
    <TransformOutOfDateOnly>false</TransformOutOfDateOnly>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Called like so:
`msbuild myProject.csproj /t:TransformAll`

Comment: Did you tag "asp.net-core" on purpose? if you are using asp.net core, you already have a project system that can generate assembly info files based on msbuild values that can be passed on commandline or calculated from date and time in the project file.

Comment: It needs to be able to build an asp.net 461 assembly as well as asp.net-core 1.1 and 2.0.  I previously edited out the asp.net-core from the title, will remove tag as well.

Comment: So your asp.net core would project already support that - `msbuild /p:Version=1.2.3.4` will set the assembly version, I recommend creating "polyfill targets" for classic projects based on the [existing source code](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk) for sdk-based projects. Don't have the time to do it now but maybe during the next days. would then behave like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43274254

Comment: [@Martin Ullrich](https://stackoverflow.com/users/784387/martin-ullrich), thank you.  I am already using powershell to call `msbuild` so `msbuild /p:Version=1.2.3.4` works perfect.  It solves my *actual* problem, but had to disable the auto increment solution with t4 templates to work.  Still would be great to know a way that works no matter where you build from..  All the same thanks!

Comment: which MSBuild you are using? located in С:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin ?

Comment: @Zam - Ultimately I solved using T4 templates.  That said any version of MSBuild that comes with VS2017 Community Edition. I believe it was `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe` - I'll provide my solution as an answer later today. It was different for `.Net 461` vs `.Net Core` and I have now migrated to only `.Net Core`

Comment: when i ran `msbuild` with this parameters ` /p:Version=1.2.3.4` version still stay the same. still looking what i did wrong. T4 -- yes, works good, but each time i need to re-save this file.

Comment: @Zam - Try this: Remove all T4 Templates, remove any edits to .csproj.  Open console where .csproj resides and run `dotnet msbuild /p:Version=1.2.3.4`.  That should work.

Answer (score 0):

U can write simple console application and in Project Properties > Build Events, add a "Pre-build event command line" like this: "D:\SomePath\MyAssemblyInfoPatcher.exe" "$(ProjectDir)Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs"

sample application code (works on VS 2022)

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

namespace MyAssemblyInfoPatcher
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (args.Length > 0)
            {
                string path = args[0].ToString();
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Current App version is set to: {0}", path));
                string now_date = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy.MM.dd.HHmm");
                if (File.Exists(path))
                {
                    string _AssemblyVersion = string.Empty;
                    string _AssemblyFileVersion = string.Empty;

                    var lines = File.ReadLines(string.Format(path));
                    for (int i = 0; i < lines.Count(); i++)
                    {
                        if (lines.ElementAt(i).ToString().StartsWith("[assembly: AssemblyVersion"))
                        {
                            _AssemblyVersion = lines.ElementAt(i).ToString();
                        }
                        else if (lines.ElementAt(i).ToString().StartsWith("[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion"))
                        {
                            _AssemblyFileVersion = lines.ElementAt(i).ToString();
                        }
                    }

                    string _replace_assembly = File.ReadAllText(path);

                    if (_AssemblyVersion != string.Empty)
                    {
                        _replace_assembly = _replace_assembly.Replace(_AssemblyVersion, string.Format("[assembly: AssemblyVersion(\"{0}\")]", now_date));
                    }
                    if (_AssemblyFileVersion != string.Empty)
                    {
                        _replace_assembly = _replace_assembly.Replace(_AssemblyFileVersion, string.Format("[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion(\"{0}\")]", now_date));
                    }

                    File.WriteAllText(path, _replace_assembly);
                }
            }   
        }
    }
}
```